# how to revise the throughput for a collection using java sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

```
 val client = new DocumentClient(endpoint, 
     masterKey, 
     new ConnectionPolicy(),
     ConsistencyLevel.Session)
 val collectionInfo = new DocumentCollection()
 collectionInfo.setId("test")
 val requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
 requestOptionsNew.setOfferThroughput(1200)
 client.createCollection("/dbs/xxx", collectionInfo, requestOptions)
```

the code snippet above helps to set throughput during creating a collection. anyone knows how to revise the throughput value for this collection?
thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To change the throughput of an existing collection, you would need to call [`replaceOffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb._document_client.replaceoffer#com_microsoft_azure_documentdb__document_client_replaceOffer_Offer_) method on DocumentClient object.

This method expects a parameter of type `Offer` and for that you will need to create an instance of [`OfferV2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb._offer_v2) class.

Comment: Thank you. I have figured out a way of changing the throughput of an existing collection based on your comment.